# svelte: How to set the head title with await?

Tags: async-await, svelte

This would be the component Product.svelte:

```svelte
<script>
    import productStore from './product-store';

    export let params = {};

    const id = parseInt(params.id);
</script>

{#await productStore.fetch(id) then product}
    <svelte:head>
        <title>{product.name}</title>
    </svelte:head>
    <h1>{product.name}</h1>
{/await}
```

This causes a compilation error:

> (plugin svelte) ParseError: svelte:head tags cannot be inside elements or blocks

How can I circumvent that, so that I get the product name in the tab as well?

<sub>Hint: Code works without the svelte:head element. productStore.fetch is an async function.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```svelte
<script>
    import productStore from './product-store.svelte';
        
    export let params = {};

    const id = parseInt(params.id);
    
    const promise = productStore.fetch(id);
</script>

 <svelte:head>
    {#await promise then product}
     <title>{product.name}</title>
    {/await}
</svelte:head>

{#await promise then product}
<h1>{product.name}</h1>
{/await}
```

Comment: Additional question: Is it possible and reasonable to put `promise = productStore.fetch(id)` into onMount?

Comment: It is possible yes. I'd say the only time you would want to do that is if you were using a dom node to figure out where you want to fetch from which seems pretty rare however.